# Docusign: Postman API collection (errorCode": "INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE)

Tags: docusignapi

I am going through this [manual](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-please-mr-postman#:%7E:text=Before%20you%20run%20this%2C%20though%2C%20you%20do%20need%20to%20make%20one%20more%20change.%20Go%20to%20the%20Headers%20tab%20in%20Postman%20and%20uncheck%20the%20Content%2DType%20header.%20The%20default%20Content%2DType%20is%20required%20for%20this%20call.) to try Docusign APIs. As you see in the link it says below the figure 8:

> Before you run this, though, you do need to make one more change. Go
> to the Headers tab in Postman and uncheck the Content-Type header. The
> default Content-Type is required for this call.

But when I uncheck this and make call I get following error:

> {
> "errorCode": "INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE",
> "message": "Content Type specified is not supported." }

I have tried unchecking it many times but still `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8` is getting through *(please note that I have enabled the logging)* in the call. All the previous calls were successful and my env variables are up-to date with manual too. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check this website, it will help you: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying the create envelope call that's mentioned in the guide? I checked my postman collection and for the same request it's using the content type `application/json`

Try setting it to that and see if it works

Comment: yes it worked, but when you imported collection your content type was `application/json` or did you edited it? you tried `/v2.1` right?

Comment: Yeah it was set to application/json by default and yeah I did use v2.1

Comment: The article you're referencing is from 2020, it may be outdated